# The meaning of "is"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verbs

As a native english speaker, I never really thought about what "is" really meant, but after starting to learn some other languages, I saw how often times, expressions with "is", were often, in the other language, used as expressions with "have". For example: EN: I'm cold. FR: J'ai froid.

This started to make me wonder what "is" actually meant. At first I though that is could just be a synonym to "equals", but that doesn't always work. (E.g. "He is sad". Not, "he equals sad.")

As of now, I have two theories as to what "is" means.

The first is that sometimes "is" can be equated to "equals" (e.g. January 15th is today.) It would be strange to say that January 15th equals today -and that statment would only be true one day of the year-, but technically, I think, that would be a correct logical statment.

The second is that "is" can also mean "the subject of this sentence currently manifests/embodies the abstract concept about to be listed" (e.g. He is sad." would follow this definition.)

What I am wanting to know is whether -and I assume that this list isn't complete- there are other definitions or stipulations concerning what "is" means.

Comment: This is a very good point that you make. Indeed I seem to recollect from when I had to study the language, about 40 years ago, that Japanese recognises this bifurcated meaning of *is*. The first complete sentence I learned was *Kore wa pen des* - (This is a pen). The *des* (verbs always go at the end in Japanese) literally means *equals*. Though sadly my recollections of the language are insufficient to say what an alternative form of the verb *to be* would be like. Is there any Japanese person out there who can help, please?

Comment: Look up 'be' at the Free Dictionary.

Comment: Look up 'be' at the OED if you can.

Comment: The two senses of "is" you give are recognized by many philosophers of language. They are called ***the "is" of identity"*** and ***the "is" of predication***. Bertrand Russell said that it was an unfortunate fact of English that we use the same for for both concepts.

Comment: As a US president once said, it all depends on what "is" is.

Comment: As a native English speaker, don't you capitalize the word English??

Comment: I would ask: What is the function of *is*; not the meaning of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wittgenstein put it,

> *Meaning* is one of the words of which one may say that they have odd jobs in our language ... What causes most trouble in philosophy is that  we are tempted to describe the use of important "odd-job" words as  though they were words with regular functions.

As it happens, only what linguists call *lexical words* have meanings. Many other words don't have meanings so much as they have **uses**. They're basically part of the grammatical rebar that's supporting all those meaningful lexical words in the sentence.

They're machinery, these words, and they don't have any meaning. So it's pointless to argue. Words like *the* and *of* and *there* and *than*; and, most relevantly, ***be***, in all its forms, in many uses.

The overwhelming majority of occurrences of *be* in English come from one of four constructions:

- auxiliary verb for the Progressive construction: *Bill **was leaving** at 5.*
- auxiliary verb for the Passive construction: *Bill **was shot** at 5.*
- auxiliary verb for all predicate adjectives: *Bill **is** sick/dead/here/hungry/tall.*
- auxiliary verb for all predicate nominals: *Bill **is** a doctor/the man to see/who she mentioned.*

Furthermore, even when *be* is the only verb in the sentence, it still behaves like an auxiliary verb.

- ***He is** going ~ **Is he** going?*
  (auxiliary verb undergoes subject-auxiliary inversion in question)
- ***This is** the one she saw. ~ **Is this** the one she saw?*
  (this *be* also behaves like an auxiliary)

In fact, no form of *be* behaves like a real lexical verb, and therefore it has no lexical meaning.  Speakers of languages without a copula, about half the people in the world, aren't surprised.

Comment: With this explanation, one feels for the Bard. Because "To be or not to be" could then be a question but not a state. Doesn't *be* often indicate a state and isn't a state lexical?

Comment: "Stative" is a property of some lexical verbs. But _be_ doesn't indicate a state; it merely appears in many constructions (like predicate adjectives and nouns) that are used to refer to states. It's also used for actions and events.

Answer (score 1):

> "...there are other definitions or stipulations concerning what "is"
>   means."

The verb *is* is a tense form of the main (infinitive) verb *be*. So, if you study the different definitions for *be*, you would be studying *is*.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/is

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be

The Present Tense uses the verb *is*.  The attributes of the Present Tense is that the present tense is used to state facts, show habitual action, but it is not used to state present action. Thus, *is* is a linking verb by itself, which is otherwise known as a "state-of-being" verb--intransitive, taking no object.

Take *is* and use it as as a helping verb (a.k.a. auxiliary verb) in verb phrase with a main verb, and you now can get all kinds of meaning, even action, as in the Present Progressive: She is going to college.

It's not a matter of *is* meaning equal, when you understand that, again used alone, it links one idea with or without a subject complement [predicate adjective/predicate nominative] to another.

The book is on the table. [adverb phrase telling *where* the book is]

That pen's ink is red. [the predicate adjective *red* *describing* the ink as being red]

She is an opera singer. [the predicate nominative *singer* modified by the adjective [nouns can be adjectives] *opera;* *identifying* or *explaining* that she is an opera singer]

Your statement, "The second is that "is" can also mean "the subject of this sentence currently manifests/embodies the abstract concept about to be listed" (e.g. He is sad." would follow this definition.)" is on cue with *is* functioning as a state-of-being verb with the purpose of being used as a linking verb:

He is sad.

Subject | linking verb | predicate adjective that answers a question an adjective would ask, "*What kind*?" What kind of feeling or emotion is he experiencing? That of being sad.

*is* alone means nothing. It's just a verb with no subject, no other words to help explain its *purpose*. I say *purpose* because after studying grammar for so long I began to see that what my textbook on grammar had been telling all the long, indirectly I might add, I had to literally put two an two together, to come up with this:

*Every word in a sentence not only functions as a part of speech but also serves a purpose in the sentence.*

And *is* is no exception. It's function is: primarily, present 3d singular of be--Webster's, and its purpose depends on how it is used: linking verb or helping verb. These rules give meaning to the word *is*. They define *is*.

Finally, our entire English language is base on a foundation: the eight parts of speech. Some laugh at this as being antiquated, irrelavant to today's linguistic/semantic advancements in grammar. There's only one problem with that, Webster's and all of these guys still use the eight parts of speech http://onelook.com/. And the last I heard is that *is* is still one of the eight parts of speech, a *verb*.

Comment: based on a foundation? Hmm